# oop comparing keys of dict to object and TypeError: 'Card' object is not iterable

Tags: python, oop

New to oop. I am trying to complete the get_value method.

```
VALUES = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10}

class Hand:
def __init__(self):
    self.cards = [] # create Hand object        

def __str__(self):
    self.string = ''
    for card in self.cards:
        self.string += card.__str__()
    return 'Hand contains ' + self.string   # return a string representation of a hand


def add_card(self, card):
    self.cards.append(card) # add a card object to a hand

def get_value(self):
    self.x = []
    for key, value in VALUES2.items():
        for card in self.cards: #also tried for card in h.cards if h = Hand()
            test2 = map(lambda each:each.strip("C"), card) #line 57                
            if key in test2:
                self.x.append(value)
    hand_value = sum(self.x)
    return hand_value
```

When I run, I get Line 57: TypeError: 'Card' object is not iterable.

```
c2 = Card("C", "2")
test_hand = Hand()
test_hand.add_card(c2)
print test_hand
```

produces

```
Hand contains C2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`map` works by applying a function to a collection of things. You are trying to use it on a single `Card` instance, hence the `TypeError`, as `map` is expecting a collection of objects as its second argument.

You can simplify your method like this, taking advantage of some properties of dictionaries:

```
def get_value(self):
    # self.x = [] - you don't need self here, as this value is only
    # local for this method.

    value = 0
    for card in self.cards:
       for item in str(card): # convert the card to its string representation
                              # giving us 'C2', then loop through each character
                              # of that string value; store it as item

          value += VALUES2.get(item, 0) # Use the .get method of dictionaries
                                        # to lookup item, if it exists, return
                                        # the value, otherwise return 0
                                        # Add the value to the total.

    return value # return the sum of all values collected
```